# Convert almost JSON string to JSON object Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have an string object like the following:

```
CustomData {
  href: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/fdsq/customData',
  createdAt: '2017-02-12T21:06:34.086Z',
  modifiedAt: '2017-02-14T20:36:45.879Z',
  ethereum_contract_address: '485dsq41g52fdsqqds',
  ethereum_provider: 'proqxy53fdsq.yoicsfdsqfdsq.net:31gky6736' }
```

I am trying to convert this string to a JSON object that I can then use properly. But i can't seem to convert this to a simple string that I could then substring and then parse to JSON.

Here is what i have attempted:

```
var rawString = req.user.customData;
console.log(rawString);
var stringJson = String(rawString).substring(0, 11);
console.log(stringJson.toString());
var customData = JSON.parse(stringJson);
console.log(customData);
```

I unfortunatly get stcuk on the JSON.parse, it seems like the string String(rawString) does not actually convert it to a string but only retruns [object Object].

Comment: If it's not JSON, it's not JSON, there's no "almost JSON", if you're going to parse strings with `JSON.parse` it **has** to be valid JSON, doublequotes and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
JSON.stringify(jsonData);
```

then just simply parse

```
JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

Comment: Nice answer, however, it does not give an explanation. The op needs an explanation because he/she is confused.

Comment: It's as simple as it is. JSON.stringify converts the data into string. JSON.parse converts a JSON-formatted string into a readable JSON

Answer (score 0):

You need `JSON.stringigy(obj);` to get a JSON-object of your data. Heres the code:

```js
var customData = {
  href: 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/fdsq/customData',
  createdAt: '2017-02-12T21:06:34.086Z',
  modifiedAt: '2017-02-14T20:36:45.879Z',
  ethereum_contract_address: '485dsq41g52fdsqqds',
  ethereum_provider: 'proqxy53fdsq.yoicsfdsqfdsq.net:31gky6736' 
}
console.log(customData);
var stringJson = JSON.stringify(customData);
console.log(stringJson);
var customData = JSON.parse(stringJson);
console.log(customData);
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomData is a JSON: It contains keys and values. JSON stands for [JavaScript Object Notation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). You confuse JSON with JSON string. From the former you can achieve the latter via

```
var JSONString = JSON.stringify(CustomData);
```

You can parse it via

```
JSON.parse(JSONString);
```

However, since your object is already a JSON, you should be able to use it properly, whatever that means in your scenario.